# How to print floating point number in C++ similar to C

Tags: c++

I want to print my data in pdb format which is a specific format of storing atomic coordinates so that they can be read by some standard molecular visualisation softwares.

Currently I am using a work around regular C++ and combining my std::cout with printf to get a desired formatted output like this,

```
std::cout << std::setw(6) << "ATOM" << std::setw(5) << "0" << " " 
          <<  std::setw(4) << "C" << std::setw(12) << global_id
          << "    ";
 printf("%8.3f %8.3f %8.3f %6.2f %6.2f \n", pos[0], pos[1], pos[2], tt, ss );
```

where global_id is an integer.

So how can I eliminate this printf and write the entire statement just by using std::cout with specified precision before and after decimal point.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see nothing secial in the formatting string you use, so you could do it all with `fixed`, `setprecision` and `setw`. By default `cout` is synchronized with `stdout` so it should work, but the synchronization can introduce needless inefficiency. Also it doesn't generalize. I would just replace `printf` with either Boost output formatting, or a `sprintf` to a suitable buffer. You can encapsulate this. That isn't what you're asking (which has a simple answer), but it's what I'd do.

Comment: Have a look at https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.format

Answer (score 2):

The mechanism you are looking for is `setprecision()` as described here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision

In conjunction with `setw()`:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw